# Cannot load/save properties of the ViewModel's property

Tags: java, zk

I have problem accessing the property of an object inside my ViewModel. I got unreached destination error. Any pointers please? Thanks.

**Error Message:**

Target Unreachable, 'toto' returned null

Basically, I will get the error when I fill in the textbox and click somewhere in the window. When I use other ViewModel's property (which is a String), it works as I expected.

**Setup:**

I use JBoss Studio. The app is running on JBoss AS 7. Basically I follow this guide http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_Maven to create my project.

**Zul file:**

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.maylab.fault.TicketsViewModel')"
        title="Trouble Ticket" width="600px" border="normal">
    <hbox style="margin-top:20px">
        <textbox value="@save(vm.toto.name)"></textbox>
        <label value="@load(vm.toto.name)"></label>
    </hbox> 
</window>
```

ViewModel:

```
package com.maylab.fault;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.*;

import com.maylab.fault.Person;

public class TicketsViewModel {

    private String ticket;
    private String test;
    private Person toto;

    public Person getToto() {
        return toto;
    }

    public void setToto(Person toto) {
        this.toto = toto;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String getTicket() {
        return ticket;
    }

    public void setTicket(String ticket) {
        this.ticket = ticket;
    }


}
```

Person class:

```
package com.maylab.fault;

public class Person {

        private String name;

        public Person(){

        }

        public Person(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it working fine for me.Can you please share more details

Comment: I use JBoss Studio. The app is running on JBoss AS 7. Basically I follow this guide http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_Maven to create my project. Tell me if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I will get the error when I fill in the textbox and click somewhere in the window. When I use the ViewModel's property (which is a String), it works as I expected.

Comment: i just tested your code in tomcat7 not aware about Jboss. I will suggest one thing try to run your application in tomcat and let me know if issue coming? This thing you did not mentioned when you are getting issue i got issue let me try to give you solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will check your viewmodel, you have wrote this code   `private Person toto;` and with `get/set` method now as you know `toto=null` so to resolve this issue you have to change your code like this

```
private Person toto = new Person();
```

this will resolve your issue.